# Why is rsync adding an extra level to my destination folder?

Tags: rsync

Hail and well met!

This is m first time using rsync, and I'm not sure how to get the results I'm expecting.

I'm trying to rsync my music library and saved playlists. My two source folders are...

```
~/music/music
~/music/playlists
```

My destination is...

```
/mnt/windows/linuxMusic
```

What I expect to see in my destination is...

```
/mnt/windows/linuxMusic/music
/mnt/windows/linuxMusic/playlists
```

What I'm getting is...

```
/mnt/windows/linuxMusic/music/music
/mnt/windows/linuxMusic/music/playlists
```

My code is...

```
src=~/music
dest=/mnt/windows/linuxMusic

rsync --archive --delete --exclude '.directory' --progress --verbose $src $dest 2>&1
```

Where is that extra "/music" coming from and how can get rid of it?

TIA!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To obtain the effect you expect, add a trailing slash to each of your directories, i.e.

```
src=~/music/
dest=/mnt/windows/linuxMusic/
```

For `rsync`, the trailing slash makes a difference.